# android saving a value from a textview

Tags: android

I made a simple counting app where there is Text-view that contains the counted number, and I want to save the counted number so that when I close the app the counted number should be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for your problem is to use SharedPreference.
create another class called SaveCounterValue and copy the following code to that class

public class SaveCounterValue {

```
static final String PREF_COUNTER= "counter";
static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
}

public static void setCounter(Context ctx, int counter)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.putInt(PREF_COUNTER, counter);
    editor.commit();
}

public static Long getCounter(Context ctx)
{
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getInt(PREF_COUNTER, 0);
}
```

}

Then in your activity after conter++ you copy the below code

SaveCounterValue.setConuter(context, counter);

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SharedPreferences`. Save the count to preference every time it is updated. Read and load the saved value in `TextView` when app starts next time.